# selenium webdriver refreshing and verify if an attribute change

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to use Python and Selenium webdriver to refreshing one page until the element stay enabled to click. The only problem is to refresh the page and make the verification.
It is a calendar to make an apointment. The code extract from the page is:

```
<tr>

<td title="Not able" class="otherMonthDay">30</td>
<td title="Not able" class="otherMonthDay">31</td>
<td title="All busy" class="calendarCellRed">1</td>
<td title="Not able" class="noSelectableDay">2</td>
<td title="All busy" class="calendarCellRed">3</td>
<td title="Not able" class="noSelectableDay">4</td>
<td title="Not able" class="noSelectableDay">5</td>

</tr>
```

And my code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()

driver.get("https://calendar page css")

for i in range (0,20):
   driver.implicitly_wait(2) # seconds
   driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Day enabled"]').click()
   driver.refresh()
   alert.accept()
```

I'd like to click on a day that turns enabled when the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that when you execute the above code you are getting a *NoSuchElementException*.

This is how my code for the same would look like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()

driver.get("https://calendar page css")

while(True):
   try:
      driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Day enabled"]').click()
      driver.refresh()
      alert.accept()
      break
   except Exception as e:
      driver.refresh()
      continue
```

Hope this helps. Do let me know in case of any questions.

Comment: Hi KevGeo,
This works for me yes!, thank you!
Now I am trying to implement to start verify the page every day at 4pm exactly. I don't know if it is possible...